# How to obtain value from span tag in selenium

Tags: python, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes

The value of page_length is 100

```
page_length = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.PaginationRow-module__container___LxZJN span.PaginationRow-module__lastPage___k9Pq7")
page_len_x = page_length.get_attribute('value')
print(str(page_len_x))
```

This is my error message :

```
page_len_x = page_length.get_attribute('value')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

The tag I'm trying to fetch is :

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text ***100*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class^='PaginationRow-module__lastPage']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[starts-with(@class, 'PaginationRow-module__lastPage')]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```